Does Hinduism give women Independence ? Can a woman have any desire?
Are women independent in Hinduism ?
Can a woman have any desire for herself ?
Does Hindu scriptures give women independence who can take decision by herself ? Can she apply her mind and take decision ?
Or Is the woman's only job is to serve her husband ?
Can they pursue Kaam and Artha by herself ? Or Should she always follow her husband ?

Related
